# El Capitan and memory

Tags: macos

Since installing El Capitan on my mid-2013 27" iMac with 16 GB of memory I often get a "not enough memory" message particularly when using Word, but also some crashes when trying to print from Word or Adobe.  I was not having any of these issues before installing El Capitan.
Any suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: When you open `Activity Monitor.app` from /Applications/Utilities, what applications/processes are using all the RAM? Can you post a screenshot of the Memory tab from Activity Monitor when this happens please?

Comment: Which versions of Office and Adobe are you running on your Mac?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**memory** could mean two things. RAM memory will clear up after you restart. And physical memory is used to store things.

Your Mac sounds young, so it might be a RAM memory problem. Try restart a few times.

If that doesn't work, type `sudo purge` into your terminal. That will manually free your RAM memory.

Lastly, there is a option to clear up NVRAM memory. If you clear NVRAM up, it will clear up your settings for system volume and mirroring and stuff. The way to do that is restart, after you hear the boot-up sound, hold down following keys: `Cmd + option + p + r`

To clear out physical memory, in the other hand, is simpler. Move things to usb and delete unwanted apps and plugins.